# Magento 2 Rest Api - Is this searchCriteria filter correct?

Tags: magento2, products, rest-api, stock-status, search-criteria

I'm trying to retrieve

- virtual products,
- which have been modified before a certain date
- and which still are in stock

I'm using this

> /rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=**updated_at**&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2019-05-25
>   00:00:00
>   &searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=lt
>
> &searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=**quantity_and_stock_status**&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
>
> &searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=**type_id**&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=virtual&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
>
> &fields=items[sku]&searchCriteria[pageSize]=100

While this returns some results, I have picked one returned sku, 
marked it as out of stock, and tried the above search again.

My problem is, my test sku which I marked out of stock, is again appearing in that search.

Is my search query correct?

--- edit ---

I'm setting the test sku as out-of-stock like this:

> PUT /rest/V1/products/test_sku/stockItems/1
>
> DATA {"stockItem":{"qty":0}}

I'm hoping this is the right way to mark an item as out of stock

---- edit 2 -----

FYI: the "Display Out of Stock Products" in my Stores>Configuration>Catalog>Inventory is set to default "No"